# How to use System.IO.File in Visual Studio's Class Library (Package)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, class-library, project.json

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and am working with one of the new options, the "Class Library (Package)".

I want to create a library that is capable of downloading files from a certain web service and saving them to whatever path is provided. It's also going to provide some other tracking and logging and so on..

When I try to use the System.IO namespace, particularly System.IO.File, I get a warning that it's not available in dotnet5.4 and is available in net451

Can I mix and match the two version of .Net in my class library? If not, can I use net451 (which I'm assuming is .Net v4.5.1 and pretty standard) only?

Below is my project.json if that helps:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "NavOnlineAutomation Class Library",
  "authors": [ "username" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can post the *.xproj file too if that helps but all I see there is generic stuff about Visual Studio, the project namespace, and output location. Nothing related to versions of .Net (which makes sense with the new project layout)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net 5.4 is a future release of the .NET framework - it looks like they will be deprecating the System.IO namespace? Which sounds odd and unlikely to me. Go ahead and use it - it is fully compatible with every build of .NET on the market today.